# How do I pass a parameter from ASP to XSL?

Tags: xslt, parameters, asp-classic

I'm writing a simple asp page to show a team rota based on some XML. Here's the XML:

```
<rota>
<shift date="20091201" primary="Chan" secondary="John" notes="notes"></shift>
<shift date="20091202" primary="Mike" secondary="Alex" notes="notes"></shift>
<shift date="20091203" primary="Ross" secondary="Mike" notes="notes"></shift>
<shift date="20091204" primary="Neil" secondary="Ross" notes="notes"></shift>
</rota>
```

I want my asp page to show today's rota details and maybe the details for the next couple of days. Since later on I'd like to be able to set a day in the future to see who's working around then I want to be able to pass a YYYYMMDD date from the ASP to the XSL that processes the XML.

Here's the XSL I have so far, just highlighting the hardcoded 'current' date for now:

```
<xsl:template match="rota">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Team Rota</title>
        <LINK type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.csfb.net/homepage/global/scripts/csfb_intranet.css"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border="1">
    <TR><TH>Date</TH><TH>Primary</TH><TH>Secondary</TH><TH>Notes</TH></TR>
    <xsl:for-each select="shift">
        <tr>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@date = '20091203'">
                    <td bgcolor='FFF0F0'><xsl:value-of select="@date"/></td>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@date"/></td>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@primary"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@secondary"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@notes"/></td>
        </tr>       
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

and here's the ASP, not yet passing any parameters:

```
''// Load the XML
sourcefile = "rota.xml"
set source = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
source.async = false
source.load(sourceFile)

''// Load the XSL
styleFile = Server.MapPath("rota.xsl")
set style = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
style.async = false
style.load(styleFile)

htmltext = source.transformNode(style)
Response.Write htmltext
```

So how do I a) pass a parameter to the XSL and b) pick up that parameter and use it in the XSL?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In you xsl create a `xsl:parameter` at the top before all your templates.

```
<xsl:parameter name="showdate"/>
```

You can now treat this like you would a variable:-

```
<xsl:when test="@date = $showdate">
```

In order to pass a parameter in you need to use an XSL processor object which allows you to add the parameter before processing.  In turn you get a processor from an instance of an XSL Template object.  In turn you need a FreeThreadedDOMDocument to assign to the templates stylesheet parameter.  Hence the code is more complex:-

```
 Dim xsl : Set xsl = CreateObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.3.0")
 xsl.async = false
 xsl.load xslFile

 Dim xml : Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
 xml.async = false
 xml.load sourceFile

 Dim xslTemplate : Set xslTemplate = CreateObject("MSXML2.XSLTemplate.3.0")
 xslTemplate.stylesheet = xsl;

 Dim processor : Set processor = xslTemplate.createProcessor()
 processor.addParameter "showDate", "20091203"
 processor.input = source
 processor.transform()  

 Response.Write processor.output
```

Its tempting to assign the Response object to the processor's output parameter which works quite well and is more efficient.  However recent Service packs of MSXML have made such a technique incompatible with ASP's implementation of IStream in the Response object.

So thats how you do it officially,  how I do it normally is to inject some arbitary attribute on to the source XML's root node then use a variable:-

```
xml.documentElement.setAttribute("_showDate", "20091203")
```

Now you can use a variable instead of a parameter inside your main template:-

```
<xsl:template match="rota">
  <xsl:variable name="showdate" select="@_showDate" />
    <html> ...
         <xsl:when test="@date = $showdate">
```

In this approach you can use the transform code you are already using which is much simpler.

Comment: I had to use this format:  
  
xml.documentElement.selectSingleNode("/rota").setAttribute("_showDate") = "20091203"

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your parameter like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... >
  <xsl:parameter name="your_parameter"/>
  <xsl:template match="rota">
      $your_parameter = <xsl:value-of select="$your_parameter" />
  ...
```

And pass it like this

```
'// Load the XSL
styleFile = Server.MapPath("rota.xsl")
set style = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.3.0")
style.async = false
style.load(styleFile)

Set template = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XSLTemplate.3.0")
template.stylesheet = style

Set processor = myTemplate.createProcessor()
processor.addParameter "your_parameter", "value"
processor.input = source
processor.output = Response
processor.transform()
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Now I'm getting: "The XSL stylesheet document must be free threaded in order to be used with the XSLTemplate object."